# How do I prevent my hero's from losing a fight?

Tags: heroville

So my hero just came back, he was about to hit level 4 but he lost so all his progress is gone. How do I prevent this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The save point blueprint will provide you with the ability to prevent heroes from restarting once they lose a battle. They will instead return to town without their gear and have to re-equip before adventuring again.